# Azure Devops Pipeline failed when running Terraform Apply

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am currently running Azure Devops Pipeline for to deploy the resources in Azure via Terraform .
In this case am failing with errors , below is my Azure Devops Yaml pipeline

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:

  - job: install_terraform
    displayName: "Installing Terraform"
    steps:
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: 'Install Terraform latest'

  - job: terraform_init
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    dependsOn: install_terraform
    steps:
      - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: 'Terraform : init'
        inputs:
          
          backendServiceArm: 'sc-test'
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: dowd-rg
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: dowd
          backendAzureRmContainerName: tfstatedowd
          backendAzureRmKey: terraform.tfstate
          

  - job: manual_approval
    displayName: "Manual Approval"
    dependsOn: terraform_init
    pool: server
    steps:
      - task: ManualValidation@0
        timeoutInMinutes: 5
        inputs:
          instructions: "Hi, please validate"

  - job: terrform_apply
    displayName: "Terraform Apply"
    dependsOn: manual_approval   
    steps:    
      - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
        displayName: 'Terraform : Apply'
        inputs:
          command: apply
          environmentServiceNameAzureRM: 'sc-test'
```

below is the screenshot of error and the error message

```
/usr/local/bin/terraform providers

│ Error: Backend initialization required, please run "terraform init"
│
│ Reason: Initial configuration of the requested backend "azurerm"
│
│ The "backend" is the interface that Terraform uses to store state,
│ perform operations, etc. If this message is showing up, it means that the
│ Terraform configuration you're using is using a custom configuration for
│ the Terraform backend.
│
│ Changes to backend configurations require reinitialization. This allows
│ Terraform to set up the new configuration, copy existing state, etc. Please
│ run │ "terraform init" with either the "-reconfigure" or "-migrate-state" flags
│ to
│ use the current configuration.
│
│ If the change reason above is incorrect, please verify your configuration
│ hasn't changed and try again. At this point, no changes to your existing
│ configuration or state have been made.

/usr/local/bin/terraform validate
╷
│ Error: Missing required provider
│ 
│ This configuration requires provider
│ registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm, but that provider isn't available.
│ You may be able to install it automatically by running:
│   terraform init
╵
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/terraform' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Terraform : Apply
```

I would like to run the pipeline i dont know what am missing here

Comment: Jobs all start from a fresh state, so you're losing your `terraform init` step. Your `terraform install` job is also useless for the same reason.

Comment: @balaganesh, may i know if there's any update after you put the terraform tasks together in one job? thanks.

Comment: @wadezhou-MSFT, I am still facing the same issue

Comment: @DanielMann, I am new to this issue ,, if you please give me a script it is much helpful

Comment: @balaganesh I told you what the problem is. Do you have a specific question or need clarification on something?

Comment: @balaganesh, have you put all terraform tasks in one job? you can refer to my sample script. If you still encounter the error, please post the new yaml so that we can check.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Backend initialization required, please run "terraform init"

You should put the `terraform install`, `init`, `plan`,`apply` steps/tasks in **one job**, as different jobs run on different agent machine, it cannot find `terraform init` in another agent.

As [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-pool-jobs) stated:
[image]

Edit:

If you would like to use different jobs and get terraform plan info in `Manual Validation` instruction, you can：

1. After your `terraform plan` step, put the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` content as an artifact, and get it in next job for `terraform apply`.
2. set `terraform plan` output as a variable, and use it in `Manual Validation` task.

Sample code as below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

stages:
  - stage: dev
    displayName: Dev
    jobs:
      - job: devplan
        displayName: Run terraform plan in dev stage
        steps:
          - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
            name: dev
            displayName: Download backend config file
            inputs:
              secureFile: "dev.azurerm.tfbackend"
          - script: |
              terraform init -backend-config=$(dev.secureFilePath)
              terraform plan -out=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dev.tfplan -var 'name=wadeRG3' -var 'location=eastus'
              content=$(terraform show -no-color dev.tfplan)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=planoutput;isOutput=true]"$content""
            displayName: Run terraform plan
            name: terraformplan
            failOnStderr: true
            env:
              ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(client-id)
              ARM_TENANT_ID: $(tenant-id)
              ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(client-secret)
              ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(subscription-id)
          
          - script: echo $(terraformplan.planoutput)

          - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
            inputs:
              targetPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
              artifact: "dev"
              publishLocation: "pipeline"
            condition: succeeded()

      - job: waitForValidation
        dependsOn: devplan
        variables:
          # map the output variable from previous job into this job
          terraformplanoutput: $[ dependencies.devplan.outputs['terraformplan.planoutput'] ]
        displayName: Wait for external validation in dev stage
        pool: server    
        timeoutInMinutes: 4320 # job times out in 3 days
        steps:   
        - task: ManualValidation@0
          timeoutInMinutes: 1440 # task times out in 1 day
          inputs:
            notifyUsers: 'xxxxxx@hotmail.com'
            instructions: '$(terraformplanoutput)'
            onTimeout: 'resume'

      - job: devapply
        dependsOn: waitForValidation
        steps:
        - download: none
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          inputs:
            buildType: "current"
            artifactName: "dev"
            targetPath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)"
          displayName: Download artifacts
        - script: |
            chmod -R a+x .terraform/*
            terraform apply --auto-approve dev.tfplan                   
          displayName: Run terraform apply
          failOnStderr: true
          workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
          env:
            ARM_CLIENT_ID: $(client-id)
            ARM_TENANT_ID: $(tenant-id)
            ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: $(client-secret)
            ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(subscription-id)
          condition: succeeded()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share full set of script with manual_approval ? please

Comment: @balaganesh, i have added the yaml sample based on your yaml. You can see there are only 2 jobs, and 2nd is depending on 1st one.

Comment: zhou , Thanks i will check this

Comment: @balaganesh, may i know if there's any update? Let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: I am still facing the issue , Could you please send a test email ? to this email id balagaanesh@gmail.com

Comment: @balaganesh, to protect your privacy, please don't expose your email in the comment. If you still have the issue, please edit your description, add the current yaml, and error screenshot, so that we can check further, thanks.

Comment: I want Azure Devops CI/CD yaml file at the stage of terraform plan i should approve it manually to trigger via email and then terraform apply should run

Comment: @balaganesh, the task `ManualValidation@0` can only be used in an **agentless job** of a YAML pipeline(doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/manual-validation-v0?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops#remarks)), it CANNOT be used in same job  with your `terraform plan` task, or other tasks which require to run on agent. You have to put it in another job. Please follow my yaml above(need to add `notifyUsers: 'your email@xxxx.com'` on the task for notification), the user should be in the organization, and member of the target project.

Comment: In the notifyUsers: 'useremail@xxxx.com' i want to show my terraform plan , the reason for am doing is in case if there is any terraform destroy comes infront , i should aware that

Comment: Hi @balaganesh, it could be a little late, but you can get the terraform plan in the `Manual Validation` content by devops variable, also achieved in different jobs. I will edit the reply, please check the details.

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost ensure that you use single quotes around resource group names, storage account names, container names, and state file names in the terraform_init job. Basically this ensures that special characters don't cause issues in the YAML.

```
- job: terraform_init
displayName: "Terraform Init"
dependsOn: install_terraform
steps:
  - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
    displayName: 'Terraform : init'
    inputs:
      command: 'init'  # Here I mean 
      backendServiceArm: 'sc-test'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'dowd-rg' 
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'dowd'  
      backendAzureRmContainerName: 'tfstatedowd'  
      backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'
```

Additionally, you can specify the command: 'init' to explicitly run the terraform init command and also make sure you provide the correct backend configuration. Also ensure that the version of Terraform you're using is compatible with your configuration(The latest version of Terraform is recommended).

Comment: None of this is a solution to the problem.

Comment: yes ... could you please share the sample terraform script with manual_approval ?